# angular $resource. Can I fake the api point for get by filtering through the response?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

(I hope the wording of my question is going to be correct, but I am not sure, let me know...)

So I have an api point for query() but not for get(). (My server answers for /foo with the complete list of foos, but not for /foo/123)

I would like to do a custom $resource action in my service, by forcing the url, and handle the filtering there (in **transformResponse**) but the problem is that at this point the param (i.e the id 123) is missing.

What would be the right way to implement that ?

EDIT: the code I currently have is :

```
 this.Foo = $resource(  '/foo/',
                        {fooId: '@fooId'},
                        {
                        get: {
                             method:'GET',
                             isArray:true,
                             url: '/foo/',
                             transformRequest: function(data, hs){
                                //data is undefined
                                console.log('transformRequest : ', data, angular.toJson(data), hs);
                                return angular.toJson(data);
                             },
                             transformResponse : function(data, headersGetter, status){
                                 //data contain the full list of foos, 
                                 //it is fine, I want to filer that based on fooId
                                 console.log('transformResponse : ', data, headersGetter, status);
                             }
                        },
```

Comment: It is for the first part that I have problems : "Use transformRequest to store the id on the config object." In my transformRequest function the data param is undefined and I do not know what to do with the headersGetter function.

Comment: Show the code for what you hace done so far.

Comment: I edited this a while ago. I dont need it anymore for now, but I am still curious as how to get it done

Comment: I am wondering, if the RESTful API can't retrieve individual resources, how does it delete individual resources? How does it update individual resources?

Comment: For that particular data, its gets erased every night, and is not updatable (messages are sent to many ppl for each creation, there is no way back.) But maybe that does not fit in a strict definition of REST.